# Access Compile error: Type mismatch on SQL Recordset Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, compiler-errors

I have an SQL query for a record set.
If I comment the query out, I do not receive the type mismatch error, so I'm relatively confident it is in this query.
The query works in the Query window in Access (without the quotes for getting it into VBA).

I get a Compile error: Type mismatch on this. It always goes to the last '&'.

I intend to move this to a string variable in the end, but I want to get it working first.

I can address the type mismatch by making the change noted below. However, now I get a 424 object required error.
If I output this to a debug window and paste the output into an SQL query window in Access, I get the result I expect.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim FileNumber As String

FileNumber = Me.txtFileNumber

Set rs = "SELECT tblParentRecord.FileNumber, tblChildRecord.CombinedName " _

& " FROM tblParentRecord INNER JOIN tblChildRecord ON tblParentRecord.FileNumber = tblChildRecord.FileNumber " _

Added: & " WHERE (((tblParentRecord.FileNumber)= " & """" & Me.FileNumber & """" & ")) "

Removed:& " WHERE (((tblParentRecord.FileNumber) LIKE'" & FileNumber & "*" & "'))')
```

Comment: Forward Progress. I changed the last line to
& " WHERE (((tblParentRecord.FileNumber)=" & Me.txtFileNumber & "));"

Now I'm getting a 424, object required error. I'll go to bat and see if I can fix this one. Later, I'll sub in a variable back where the linkage to the form is so that I can extract this into a module. I'll repost the final code if I fix it. If anyone has easy advice, I'll take it.

Comment: I think there should be a space after like.  WHERE tblParentRecord.FileNumber) LIKE '" & FileNumber & "* ' "

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that's it. I had this output to a MsgBox as a string, then I pasted the output into a fresh SQL query window. I still got the error until I put quotes around the FileNumber variable output. I can't figure out how to keep the variable reference and add quotes in VBA. I tried using Chr(34) which looks good in Msgbox and works when I paste into my Query window, but still outputs the error.  I tried & """ & FileNumber & """, but it causes VBA to read FileNumber as text instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim FileNumber As String
Set db = CurrentDb



FileNumber = Me.txtFileNumber

strSql = "SELECT tblParentRecord.FileNumber, tblChildRecord.CombinedName " _
  & " FROM tblParentRecord INNER JOIN tblChildRecord ON tblParentRecord.FileNumber = tblChildRecord.FileNumber " _
  & " WHERE tblParentRecord.FileNumber Like '" & FileNumber & "' "

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)
```

Comment: I was just about to post my result, but decided to refresh first. This is, essentially what I did. 

Changed: rsQuery = "SELECT tblParentRecord.FileNumber, tblChildRecord.CombinedName " _

& " FROM tblParentRecord INNER JOIN tblChildRecord ON tblParentRecord.FileNumber = tblChildRecord.FileNumber " _

& " WHERE (((tblParentRecord.FileNumber)= " & """" & Me.FileNumber & """" & ")) "

Added: Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet(rsQuery) <<this was the problem.